# jQuery Address META tag preservation

Tags: php, jquery, seo, meta-tags, jquery-address

I am using jQuery Address for AJAX navigation. I would like to preserve the META tags for SEO.

Is there a tried and true way to accomplish this? I cannot find anything on the Asual site regarding this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick glance at it suggests that:

If `pushState` is available, it will use it. For `pushState` URIs you just need to build the underlying page at the URI.

If `pushState` is not available, it will revert to using fragment identifiers. These are entirely JS dependent and you can forget about SEO for them. It doesn't appear to support Google's [hash-bang](http://isolani.co.uk/blog/javascript/BreakingTheWebWithHashBangs) hack.